# How can I create ONLY one boxplot from a matrix in R?

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and I would like to know how can I can I create a single boxplot for a matrix. I've tried everything I could and it seems to always create a boxplot for each line. Appreciate the help.

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us your code and a snippet of your data that are causing multiple boxplots.

Comment: Can you add sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe by default, it creates a boxplot for each column so the idea is to filter only for one column.

```
library(tidyverse)
# good
matrix(1:12, nrow = 4)[,1] %>% boxplot()
# not good (without filtering)
matrix(1:12, nrow = 4) %>% boxplot()
```

If you really require to use all numbers from the matrix, you can use as.vector function.

```
library(tidyverse)
matrix(1:12, nrow = 4) %>% as.vector() %>% boxplot()
```

Or this way without using tidyverse library.

```
boxplot(as.vector(matrix(1:12, nrow = 4)))
```

Comment: tried what you are saying and it gave me an error "could not find function "%>%", what do you think i should do?

Comment: Sorry about that. Try this: boxplot(as.vector(matrix(1:12, nrow = 4)))

I used an additional library that you probably do not have installed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly then what you want is a single boxplot for all the data in all the columns of your matrix, right? If so, then convert your matrix to a dataframe, `unlist` the columns, and draw your boxplot on that single vector:

```
set.seed(12)
mtx <- matrix(NA, nrow = 8, ncol = 4)
mtx[] <- rnorm(4, 1, 0.5)
mtx
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.4963505 0.4963505 0.4963505 0.4963505
[2,] 1.9633594 1.9633594 1.9633594 1.9633594
[3,] 1.0257152 1.0257152 1.0257152 1.0257152
[4,] 1.9002619 1.9002619 1.9002619 1.9002619
[5,] 0.4963505 0.4963505 0.4963505 0.4963505
[6,] 1.9633594 1.9633594 1.9633594 1.9633594
[7,] 1.0257152 1.0257152 1.0257152 1.0257152
[8,] 1.9002619 1.9002619 1.9002619 1.9002619
```

Now convert the matrix:

```
df <- as.data.frame(mtx)
```

Assemble the data in one vector by unlisting the columns:

```
alltogether <- unlist(df[,1:4])
```

Draw your boxplot:

```
boxplot(alltogether)
```